# Windows 8.1 My Documents/Pictures/Videos new location shows in all old places

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, network-shares, my-documents, network-location

In an effort to help domain users not save to their local hard drives and only save to their (backed-up, secure) personal network shared drive, we have a practice of setting their default save location to their network drive (in this case it is a mapped drive called M:).

To do this we [changed the location](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/redirect-folder-new-location#1TC=windows-7) of their "My Documents" folder to the mapped network drive (M:). I also would do the same with "My pictures", "my videos", etc. Now when the user tries save a new document, the first place that shows up by default is M:.

This worked great with the assumption that they were connected to the network and they were using Windows 7. When I did this with Windows 8, it behaved very differently. Specifically, it would start displaying the folders like library folders and additionally now rename them ALL to their moved location. Now there are 4 of them. Check out this screenshot:

[image: 4 network drives]

They appear to work just like the network drive (most of the time). But, since this won't behave like Windows 7 used to, I would like to just get rid of them or hide them to save user confusion ("why do I have 4 or 5 M: drives??").

After playing with things and googling, I cannot find a way to hide them or rename them (preserving the desired redirect functionality). How can I do this?

I even have a situation where they display *differently* in the same navigation pane.

[image: weird display scenario]

Any help is apprecitated.

Answer (score 0):

**An answer proposed by a friend:**

My problem is I am mapping the folders to the root of `M:`, and Windows 8.1 appears to mirror the mapped folder name. If I were to create a folder underneath `M:` called "Pictures", "Videos", etc. Then map each folder to the respective subfolder under `M:`, it should reflect the expected name, instead of `M:` or `Documents`.

**Disclaimer: I have not tried this solution yet -  I will update this if/when I do try it.**